# Evaluating a triple integral explained step by step

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate:
$$ \iiint_{D}\sqrt{(1-9z^2)(1-4y^2-9z^2)}\,dx\,dy\,dz$$
where $D$ is the domain:

$$D: x^2 +4y^2+9z^2\le1$$

Can someone tell me if my steps are correct?

$$\int_{\frac{-1}{3}}^{\frac{1}{3}} \, dz\iint_{\{ \frac{x^2}{1-9z^2}+\frac{y^2}{\frac{1}{4}(1-9z^2)} \le1 \}}\sqrt{(1-9z^2)(1-4y^2-9z^2)} \,dx\,dy $$

The last double integral is composed by the following integrals:
$$\int_{-\sqrt{1-9z^2}}^{+\sqrt{1-9z^2}} \, dx \int_{-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-9z^2}}^{+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-9z^2}}\,\sqrt{(1-9z^2)(1-4y^2-9z^2)} dy$$

Since both integral don't depend on $z$ I can write:$$ \iiint_{D}f\,dx\,dy\,dz=2\int_{\frac{-1}{3}}^{\frac{1}{3}}\sqrt{1-9z^2}\sqrt{1-9z^2}\,dz \int_{-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-9z^2}}^{+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-9z^2}}\sqrt{1-4y^2-9z^2}\,dy$$
Here I've already done the first integral which depends on $x$.

So we have to calculate:$$\int_{\frac{-1}{2}a}^{\frac{1}{2}a} \sqrt{a^2-4y^2}\, dy$$ where $a^2=1-9z^2$; we can consider $a$ as a constant.
Now let $y=\frac{1}{2}a\sin(t)$, we have:
$$dy=\frac{1}{2}a\cos(t)dt$$ The last integral I wrote turns into:$$\frac{1}{2}a^2\int_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}^{\frac{+\pi}{2}}\left | \cos(t) \right |\cos(t)dt$$ which can be written as:$$a^2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^2(t)dt=a^2\left [ \frac{t}{2} +\frac{\sin(t)\cos(t)}{2}\right ]\begin{matrix} \frac{\pi}{2} \\0\end{matrix}=\frac{\pi}{4}a^2$$

Finally:$$ \iiint_{D}f\,dx\,dy\,dz=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{\frac{-1}{3}}^{\frac{1}{3}}(1-9z^2)^2\,dz$$

In my schoolbook the solution is $\frac{64}{135}$...so where is the mistake in my method?

Comment: I haven't yet carefully read your whole post, but I see the domain of integration is of a certain type. Have you tried elliptical coordinates?

Comment: not yet...my book doesn't talk about them.